# scrolling messes up the header in jtable when using non default header height

Tags: java, jtable, jtableheader

I change the height of header in jtable with this:

```
mytable.getTableHeader().setPreferedSize(new Dimension(mytable.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), 34));
```

And now, when i use horizontal scrollbar, the header doesn't get rendered correctly at all. What am i doing wrong? This is the only line that affects the problem. Do i need to do anything else to change the height of the header?

[Here is the screenshot of the problem.](http://www.net-isle.com/problem.png)  Look at right of the header...

Comment: You may wish to consider creating and posting an http://sscce.org that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: i'd write and sscce but i can't replicate the problem on simple project and so far i'm unable to pinpoint where could the problem be.

i guess i'm off to debugging...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension d = table.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize();
d.height = 34;
table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(d);
```

Comment: still nothing... i'm updating the question with screenshot, so you get the idea what's wrong.

Comment: The code works fine for me. A screen shot doesn't help. You need to post your SSCCE as was suggested earlier.

Comment: hm. it seems to work for me too in simple new project. seems something else is bothering him, yet it's only visible when header height changes... i'm also using cell renderers for non-header rows. perhaps that?

Comment: That is why we need a SSCCE and why a SSCCE should be created for every question. We don't know how you have customized your code.

Comment: The thing is that i can't see any reason for this to happen. This is the only line that's causing the problem. Even if i set the height the same as default (remove 2nd line from your code), it still happens. I disabled custom renderers, look and feel etc... and only call that i left is setPreferredSize. I'm totally lost.